# Download multimedia message with WiFi calling enabled

Tags: mms, google-messages

I find that if I get sent an MMS message while connected to WiFi calling it never downloads. And retrying the download never works either.

Galaxy s4
Google messaging app

Comment: I think this is a problem with the carrier because I have never had MMS download while wifi calling is on work. I have had 3 different phones that supported wifi calling over the past couple years. Multiple manufacturers (Samsung Galaxy S1, Samsung Note 2, amd LG G3). I've never found a way to get them to come through except turn off wifi, then re-enable wifi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So I called up Sprint. They told me that having WiFi calling enabled doesn't allow for MMS download because it makes the phone use all its bandwidth from the WiFi for calling, none for those messages.

So theoretically if you have WiFi but not WiFi calling enabled you should get the messages.